# Google Analytics from External Site display in our internal sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, external-data-column, google-analytics

Currently we use google analytics for our external outside facing site. The OOB reports are handy but we often export the results into excel and coorelate the data with other data using the url as a unique indicator and vlookups.

I would like to something similar using a SharePoint list so I don't have to download cut and paste etc. Ideally it would just pull custom GA reports in and compare it with existing data on a SharePoint list. Is there a way to do this using an api or something?

I am a complete sharepoint noob so if it's highly technical you can just tell me to go back to my "little excel spreadsheets"